# Setup DLL does not work when CAB installs on Windows CE

Tags: c++, dll, installation, windows-ce, installshield

I am trying to install multi CAB files using custom Setup DLL. More precisely, after my application CAB installs, I want .NET CF 3.5 CAB file to be installed as well.

My device platform is as follows:

Windows Mobile 6 Classic
CE OS 5.2.1433
Processor: ARM920T

And I made my custom Setup DLL with Visual Studio 2005 and I followed the instructions posted on

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504675(v=WinEmbedded.60).aspx

(Optional Setup.dll Files for Installation for Windows Embedded CE 6.0 R3)

And then I made my CAB file with InstallShield Professional 6.31
I am expecting to see .TXT file as it is described in the instructions.
However, nothing happens. All the application files get installed, but Setup DLL does not seem to run.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

By the way, when I install my CAB file on my device I get the following warning:

> *The program you have installed may not display properly because it was
>   designed for a previous version of
>   Windows Mobile software.*

Would this cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is likely because  Microsoft at some point (I can't recall which version of WinMo it changed) changed wceload to be a singleton app, meaning that your setup dll, which is being run inside wceload, cannot spawn another instance of wceload.  Fun eh?

The warning is becasue the INF file used to generate the CAB has stamped the supported version of the OS to something lower than what tyou're installing on.  I know how to change it in the INF, but no idea how with InstallShield.